# Best architecture to filter data from 90 million users?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-kafka, cassandra

This is purely hypothetical question as I recently started studying distributed systems.

### The Overview:

- User has a shopping app.
- User does actions (register, views, buys, multiple views, etc).
- User receives real time campaigns and recommendation based on what he's currently doing.

### The Problem:

- Having real time recommendations for potentially over 30 millions of incoming events a second.

### The Challenge:

- Filtering through the data, applying recommendations, sending it back.

---

### What I thought of so far below.

- Use Cassandra to store the actions data. (Because Cassandra is highly scalable and we do not care about ACID guarantees, we care about high availability)
- Use HDFS With Spark and Kafka. (To process data, but I'm not sure here)

This is the flow I thought:

1. User performs an action
2. Action goes to the API (Through LBs)
3. Action gets registered in Cassandra
4. API Notifies a worker (possibly celery?) of an action that just happened
5. The Worker queries the data on Cassandra
6. The work sends the data to Kafka
7. Kafka sends the data to Spark
8. Spark Process the data with Machine Learning
9. A new custom action (i.e. discounts, recommendations, etc) will be made specifically tailored by the User's actions
10. Spark sends the data back to Kafka
11. Kafka sends data to Users
12. User will display the custom action it received from the server

Please correct me on anything faulty or if there's a better, scalable way to do it. I'm still learning about all those different components and how they may fit together.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by looking at it differently: you want to be able to provide a recommendation to a user in a responsive way.

1. How big is the results data being sent to each user? Let's say 10KB.
2. How big is the database that has to be searched to generate that result? Let's say 1GB.
3. What i/o throughput do you get from your chosen size of cloud server? Let's say one server can serve 10 000 users per second.
4. 30 million requests divided by 10 000 users equals 3000 servers.

So your first problem is how to replicate 1GB of data to 3000 servers. And if you want responses back, your second problem is how to synchronise 3000 copies.

The first isn't too hard: replicating data from a central copy out to 3000 servers is fairly easy - it's what content delivery networks do. And if only small portions of the data change at any one time it can be quite fast and efficient.

For responses, the solution will depend on the data. The hypothetical worst case is for any one answer to be needed by all servers immediately i.e. 3000 servers each broadcasting to the other 2999. This is unlikely to work!!

If the data isn't needed on all servers simultaneoulsy then you could implement a 'telephone tree' approach where each server notifies 10 others, which in turn notify 10 others, and so on. But this limits your flexibility to deploy servers.

Anyway I hope this has given you something to think about and a way to determine whether the software you are considering meets the needs of the problem.

Comment: Good approach but I don't know if I agree with that server calculations. What kind of connection are you basing those calculations on that the server can handle? Are you talking about polling, http polling, web sockets? 10 kb also seems somewhat excessive for user events, I would argue 200 bytes, possibly less. With 90 million users sending an average of 5 events a day with an average of 200 bytes per event, we might be talking about 1 mb a second everyday payload.

Comment: For 90 million users sending an average of 5 requests a day, we're talking about 450 million requests every day, 450 / 84600 = ~5,300 requests per second. So, according per your calculations a single server would be able to handle the load. But we could expand and replicate for safety.  To store those events forever, in five years we would have: 90 million * 5 events a day * 200 bytes = 90 GB * 365 days * 5 years = 164 TB storage

Comment: If we're using a wide-column non-relational database we could possibly have lower/bigger storage size depending on the row, as opposed to a relational one that would store the unfilled column as 'null' or something of the sort. So, that does make a wide-column database seem more appealing at first glance. Since we don't care about consistency it's the way to go.

Comment: I'm having difficulties understanding how hadoop would fit into all of this since we're talking about data in the database I wouldn't need HDFS. I could process the data using MQ and a worker. Then I could use Pulsar/Kafka to stream the campaign/recommendation back to the user in real time.

Comment: @Madd World. The figures I used are purely illustrative. If you apply your own figures then you can see which bits of the problem are the most critical.  I can't help you with a definite recommendation on Kafka etc because I don't know enough about the real problem and the nature of your real data.

Comment: @Madd World Re your point on 'one server'. Don't forget that (a) https adds a lot of overhead and (b) requests are often 'bursty'. But Amazon's 'AWS API Gateway' can support up to 10K per second so one of those would meet your requirement. Plus you then get plain http internally to your server(s) which improves performance. So you now only need to look at IOPS for AWS servers to see how many you'll need. HTH